# How can I get sed to only match to the first occurrence of a character?

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I'm using **GNU Sed 4.2.1**. I'm trying to replace the second field in the following line (the password in */etc/shadow*). `Awk` is not an option.

```
username:P@s$w0rDh@$H:15986:0:365::::
```

I've tried

```
sed -i 's/\(^[a-z]*\):.*?:/\1:TEST:/'
```

but nothing. I've tried many variations but for some reason I can't get it to only match that field. Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `[^:]*` to match everything up until the next `:`

```
sed -i 's/^\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):/\1:TEST:/'
```

Comment: Perfect! I forgot [^] as an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^\([^:]*:\)[^:]*\(.*\)$/\1foo\2/' file
```

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -F: '{$2="foo"}1' OFS=: file
```

Comment: awk not an option says the OP, not sure why

Comment: @1_CR: Ok sed solution also provided.

Comment: Awk isn't an option because the edit has to be in-place. Permissions and stuff.